# Horizontal scrolling on mobile devices with Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I´m looking for the best way to realize **horizontal scrolling** like shown here https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6 with default elements in Bootstrap 5 CSS framework. Is there a "best practice" how to realize that with Bootstrap 5?

Comment: There is nothing like this in the bootstrap framework (except for [carousels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/)). I don't see why you can't just use the layout and CSS explained in the tutorial as is? You could even use bootstraps .card

Comment: Thanks @GrahamReynolds, that´s the way i did it now...